# Android Studio jsonResult error?

Tags: android

i kinda new with android studio, and i am working with some registration code, and got some error.  so what i wanna ask is this :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
        if(result.equals("") || result == null){
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
        if(jsonResult == 0){
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Invalid username or password or email or name or hp or address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if(jsonResult == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("USERNAME", enteredUsername);
            intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully Registered");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

the prob is when i fill all the registration need, i hit the sign up button and then this happened :
[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjJxg.png)

SO, i hope i can find a solution with your all help. thanks.

---------------------------EDITED----------------------------

**SignUpActivity**

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected EditText username;
private EditText password;
private EditText email;
private EditText name;
private EditText hp;
private EditText address;

protected String enteredUsername;
private final String serverUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/androidlogins/index.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_field);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_field);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_field);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_field);
    hp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hp_field);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_field);
    Button signUpButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_up);

    signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enteredUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String enteredPassword = password.getText().toString();
            String enteredEmail = email.getText().toString();
            String enteredName = name.getText().toString();
            String enteredHp = hp.getText().toString();
            String enteredAdd = address.getText().toString();

            if(enteredUsername.equals("") || enteredPassword.equals("") || enteredEmail.equals("") || enteredName.equals("")
                    || enteredHp.equals("") || enteredAdd.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Username or Password or Email or Name or Handphone or Address must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if(enteredUsername.length() <= 1 || enteredPassword.length() <= 1){
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Username or password length must be greater than one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            // request authentication with remote server4
            AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
            asyncRequestObject.execute(serverUrl, enteredUsername, enteredPassword, enteredEmail, enteredName, enteredHp, enteredAdd);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sign_up, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        String jsonResult = "";
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[1]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[2]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", params[3]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", params[4]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hp", params[5]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", params[6]));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            System.out.println("Returned Json object " + jsonResult.toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonResult;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
        if(result.equals("") || result == null){
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
        if(jsonResult == 0){
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Invalid username or password or email or name or hp or address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if(jsonResult == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, Login2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("USERNAME", enteredUsername);
            intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully Registered");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

    JSONObject resultObject = null;
    int returnedResult = 0;
    try {
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnedResult;
}
```

}

**LoginActivity**

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
protected EditText username;
private EditText password;
protected String enteredUsername;
private final String serverUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/androidlogins/index.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_field);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enteredUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String enteredPassword = password.getText().toString();

            if (enteredUsername.equals("") || enteredPassword.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username or password must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if (enteredUsername.length() <= 1 || enteredPassword.length() <= 1) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username or password length must be greater than one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            // request authentication with remote server4
            AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
            asyncRequestObject.execute(serverUrl, enteredUsername, enteredPassword);
        }
    });

    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        String jsonResult = "";
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[1]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[2]));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
        if (result.equals("") || result == null) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
        if (jsonResult == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (jsonResult == 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Login2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("USERNAME", enteredUsername);
            intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully login");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
}

private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result) {

    JSONObject resultObject = null;
    int returnedResult = 0;
    try {
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnedResult;
}
```

}

**Login2Activity**

```
public class Login2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle intentBundle = intent.getExtras();
    String loggedUser = intentBundle.getString("USERNAME");
    loggedUser = capitalizeFirstCharacter(loggedUser);
    String message = intentBundle.getString("MESSAGE");

    TextView loginUsername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_user);
    TextView successMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
    loginUsername.setText(loggedUser);
    successMessage.setText(message);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login2, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private String capitalizeFirstCharacter(String textInput){
    String input = textInput.toLowerCase();
    String output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
    return output;
}
```

}

Comment: Have a look at your server-side code!

Comment: what is the `json` your getting in result???

Comment: Where is your `returnParsedJson` method and what is your error? Also, this error has nothing to do with Android Studio and your variable could be named anything instead of "jsonResult", so your question is a bit vague.

Comment: sorry, did you look at the screenshot image ?

Comment: wait, i will post all the activity code. i kinda new with this all. sorry then